# Trying to reuse the code by taking series of Input using jOptionPane

Tags: java, joptionpane

I am new to jOptionPane and I am trying to achieve the following task. Please consider the following code for explanation purpose:

```
purchaseAmount = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Item Purchase Amount"));

            if(onepty.budgetAmountVerify(purchaseAmount)){

            itemNo ++;

            itemCheck = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                                 "Would you like to Enter More Items?", "Say Yes or No", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); 

            if (itemCheck == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){ // For Yes JOptionPane.YES_OPTION returns 0 and for No it returns 1





             }
             else if (itemCheck == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)s{

             }
```

Variable Related Information :

- purchaseAmount is a double type variable
- itemNo is an integet type variable
- onepty is an object of a data definition class where  budgetAmountVerify method is defined.
- itemCheck is an Integer type variable

What I am trying to Achieve :

As soon as `if` condition is encountered and if the user has selected `YES` as his option, I would like to take the user to the same dialogbox which is defined just above the `if` condition, basically the following :
`purchaseAmount = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Item Purchase Amount"));` . This will help me in achieving the following things:

1. I would have to write the above piece of code again and again if user clicks on Yes option again and again.
2. I can get a proper count of `items`, since after entering the `if` condition, I am increasing the count by 1.

Is there a way to achieve what I am looking for? Because my ultimate goal is to print the purchaseamount , itemNo value in the else condition when user doesn't clicks on No option and basically stops entering new item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the whole code in a do while loop.
Such that if the user selects YES option the loop iterates.

```
do{
        purchaseAmount = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Item Purchase Amount"));

        if(onepty.budgetAmountVerify(purchaseAmount)){

        itemNo ++;

        itemCheck = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                             "Would you like to Enter More Items?", "Say Yes or No", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); 
}
while(itemCheck == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
```

In short replace if with do while